# How to use autolayout to create a "center-anchored" quad style layout?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout, interface-builder

I am creating an OSX Desktop application and am struggling with autolayout. I would like to create a quad view where four subviews are anchored to the corners of the parent window. When the window expands I would like to expand the subviews "toward the center" so that the border between them remains fixed and each subview expands equally. I have no idea how to do this.

Expressed another way, I would like the "border" between these views to remain the same no matter the window size. I'm fine with fixing one dimension.

[image]

This seems simple but I'm struggling mightily with autolayout and I just don't understand how to express it in terms of constraints that "distribute" the space equally between neighboring views. How to do this?  Code is welcome, but really I just want an explanation of the theory of operation. The closest I've been able to come is to specify a required constraint between the boxes, but then they resize (arbitrarily?) to satisfy this constraint, which isn't what I want at all.

I've read through the Apple docs on autolayout and constraints several times but can't seem to make the leap to implementing real world layouts such as these. I've found a handful of tutorials but they seem a bit outdated and/or focused on rants about IB versus code for constraints (I don't care which method, as long as it works ;) ) Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah... the "secret" was creating a relative constraint between the views, or a "Equal Width" and "Equal Height" constraint. Each of the four should look more or less like:

[image]